# React PWA App, Blank page after rebuild and deploy. File hashes changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a react application which uses a service worker to register as a PWA.

(NOTE This is NOT running as an installed PWA at present)

After a new build of the application the app shows a blank white page unless you clear the browser cache.

The following error can be found in the console:

> Refused to execute script from
> 'https://[MYSITE]/static/js/main.5499eb74.js' because its MIME type
> ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
> enabled.

Looking at this I can see two things:
First the response for `main.5499eb74.js` is returning the index page (some lines omitted for brevity):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>   
<meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>   
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/>
<script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.9f20fe6e.js"></script>
<link href="./static/css/main.3d186e11.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

From this I notice that the HTML contains `main.9f20fe6e.js` which is different from `main.5499eb74.js`

On build the file hash has changed (as you would expect), however the service worker is loading and old index document with `main.5499eb74.js` (first request response, returned from service worker):

```
...
<script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.5499eb74.js"></script>
...
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Either the service worker should be loading a cached version of the `main.5499eb74.js` or it should realise it needs to load the index from the server (or both)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is seen because the service worker is caching 'index.html' which has references to your earlier build chunks.

Refer to the following SO thread to figure out how to fix it.

[How to handle caching of index.html file with service worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829663/how-to-handle-caching-of-index-html-file-with-service-worker)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache before building your application.
But this link can explain the reason for this anomaly clearly: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74057337)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was related to this error / warning in the build log (which I didn't notice as we use CI:

```
/static/js/main.da1f27cc.js is 6.13 MB, and won't be precached. Configure maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes to change this limit.
```

Installing and setting maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes in craco-workbox has fixed this issue